# Is laptop CPU running at constant Turbo Clock speed bad?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, memory, cpu, performance

I'm not exactly sure why, but since yesterday, my laptop CPU has been running at its turbo clock speed, constantly, when idle and no applications are open. In task manager, my CPU usage is below 10%, however the speed is always at around 3.0 GHz, when it used to be at 2.6 GHz when idle. It also says that the maximum speed is 2.59 GHz, which obviously doesn't make sense...

I don't exactly feel that the laptop is hotter in temperature, however I don't want it to overheat. In my laptop specification descriptions, it says turboclock speed can go up to 3.2 GHz, which is close to what I have right now, whether idle or running applications.

I don't mind this new development, it makes my laptop quite faster, however I just want to make sure it won't do any damage, in terms of lifespan, battery usage, or laptop in general. If something can go wrong, how do I change it back to the normal clock rate at idle, and only make it go turbo when running games?

My specs,

- Dell Latitude E7450
- i7-5600U
- Intel HD Graphics 5500 mobile
- 8 GB RAM

Comment: Intel CPUs are designed to use the Turbo Boost feature.  Additionally, CPU usage, isn’t required for Turbo Boost to be enabled.  If your laptop isn’t automatically shutting down then it’s not overheating.  I suggest resetting your laptops firmware settings.

Comment: Intel CPUs are designed to throttle to protect themselves from overheating, so you don't need to worry about damage.  I would not be surprised if your battery runtime decreased slightly.   I'm not a Windows person - so I could be talking garbage - but I would be inclined to check if this only happens when on AC power (in which case no problem), and check the power profiles to see if there is a lower power configuration you can switch to which throttles back the CPU.

Comment: @Ramhound since it's not shutting down automatically, there shouldn't be any problems with the cpu's life expectancy? It won't die out quicker would it? I really prefer having the faster version, however I don't want the constant turbo feature to ruin the laptop's life...

Comment: @davidgo what you said does make sense... It happens on both AC and battery, and I'm on the batter saver option for both. The only concern is any permanent damage that could be done if it always, I mean alwayssss, runs on turboboost.

Comment: The fact that you can turbo constantly means your cooling is adequate, and your computer would shut down if overheating, and would attempt to throttle before that, so there's nothing to worry about.